# std.net.curl application throws an exception

Tags: curl, libcurl, d

I try to compile this program from [std.net.curl](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_net_curl.html)

```
import std.net.curl, std.stdio;

void main()
{
    auto range1 = byLineAsync("www.google.com");
    auto range2 = byLineAsync("www.wikipedia.org");
    foreach (line; byLineAsync("dlang.org"))
        writeln(line);

    foreach (line; range1) writeln(line);
    foreach (line; range2) writeln(line);
}
```

I compile this program like this.

> $ dmd internet.d -ofinternet

or

> dmd -I/usr/include/dmd/phobos -L-l:libcurl.so.4.2.0 internet.d -ofinternet

The program compiles fine but it throws an exception.

```
std.concurrency.PriorityMessageException@std/concurrency.d(273): Priority message
----------------
 ??:? _D3std11concurrency10MessageBox160__T3getTDFS3std11concurrency3TidS3std3net4curl21__T11CurlMessageTAyaZ11CurlMessageZbTDFS3std11concurrency3TidS3std3net4curl19__T11CurlMessageTbZ11CurlMessageZbZ3getMFDFS3std11concurrency3TidS3std3net4curl21__T11CurlMessageTAyaZ11CurlMessageZbDFS3std11concurrency3TidS3std3net4curl19__T11CurlMessageTbZ11CurlMessageZbZ3ptyMFKS3std11concurrency36__T4ListTS3std11concurrency7MessageZ4ListZb [0x81d03f4]
??:? bool std.concurrency.MessageBox.get!(bool delegate(std.concurrency.Tid, std.net.curl.CurlMessage!(immutable(char)[]).CurlMessage), bool delegate(std.concurrency.Tid, std.net.curl.CurlMessage!(bool).CurlMessage)).get(bool delegate(std.concurrency.Tid, std.net.curl.CurlMessage!(immutable(char)[]).CurlMessage), bool delegate(std.concurrency.Tid, std.net.curl.CurlMessage!(bool).CurlMessage)) [0x81cfeed]
??:? void std.concurrency.receive!(bool delegate(std.concurrency.Tid, std.net.curl.CurlMessage!(immutable(char)[]).CurlMessage), bool delegate(std.concurrency.Tid, std.net.curl.CurlMessage!(bool).CurlMessage)).receive(bool delegate(std.concurrency.Tid, std.net.curl.CurlMessage!(immutable(char)[]).CurlMessage), bool delegate(std.concurrency.Tid, std.net.curl.CurlMessage!(bool).CurlMessage)) [0x81cfd08]
??:? void std.net.curl.AsyncLineInputRange!(char).AsyncLineInputRange.__mixin5.tryEnsureUnits() [0x81ccb87]
??:? @property bool std.net.curl.AsyncLineInputRange!(char).AsyncLineInputRange.__mixin5.empty() [0x81cc7db]
??:? _Dmain [0x81b47b8]
??:? _D2rt6dmain211_d_run_mainUiPPaPUAAaZiZ6runAllMFZ9__lambda1MFZv [0x81d9292]
??:? void rt.dmain2._d_run_main(int, char**, extern (C) int function(char[][])*).tryExec(scope void delegate()) [0x81d91dc]
??:? void rt.dmain2._d_run_main(int, char**, extern (C) int function(char[][])*).runAll() [0x81d924e]
??:? void rt.dmain2._d_run_main(int, char**, extern (C) int function(char[][])*).tryExec(scope void delegate()) [0x81d91dc]
??:? _d_run_main [0x81d916e]
??:? main [0x81d3393]
??:? __libc_start_main [0x129532]
```

I use dmd v2.072.0

Comment: You could perhaps try to use the dlang-requests - https://github.com/ikod/dlang-requests

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug, perhaps you should report it to https://issues.dlang.org/.

For asynchronous network programming, most people would use Vibe.d, though: http://vibed.org/